# error when Inserting Data from VB.net to MS Access Database Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when I try to insert data from `VB.net` to `MS Access` Database Table. My code is:

```
Try
            Dim d As New DBConnect
            Dim indx As Integer
            indx = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            d.Editdata(String.Format("INSERT INTO Client (ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit, ClientLastPay) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", FlatTextBox1.Text, FlatTextBox2.Text, FlatTextBox3.Text, FlatTextBox4.Text, FlatTextBox5.Text))
            Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

by debugging the error is in this line :

```
d.Editdata(String.Format("INSERT INTO Client (ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit, ClientLastPay) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", FlatTextBox1.Text, FlatTextBox2.Text, FlatTextBox3.Text, FlatTextBox4.Text, FlatTextBox5.Text))
```

picture of the error : **https://s31.postimg.org/ew7cxpfy3/Sans_titre.png** .

hope for your help ?

Comment: This is one of the many errors that you can expect to happen if you use string cancatenation instead of a parameterized query.(And not the most serious one)  Someone of your string values is not correct for the underlying column. What is the schema of your Client table?

Comment: look at this pic of shema `http://up.dev point.com/uploads1/d3c02d2f78451.png`

Comment: thanks ! i solve the problem easly :)

Comment: Then, please post your own answer or delete this question

Comment: ok i will post the answer

Comment: the solution is this line : `d.Editdata(String.Format("INSERT INTO Client (ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit, ClientLastPay) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", FlatTextBox1.Text, FlatTextBox5.Text, FlatTextBox2.Text, FlatTextBox3.Text, FlatTextBox4.Text))`

Comment: Now suppose that your user inputs for the ClientName the word **"O'Brian"** (note the quote between O and B) What happens?